# What is the dataweave expression to map an arraylist to a copybook?

Tags: mule, runtime-error, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am building a copybook request for IBM MQ and in the request I have to send an arraylist of elements having values. I am getting the exception

`too few values for 'IO-ARRAY' of segment COMMAREA at position 0 (com.mulesoft.flatfile.lexical.WriteException)`.

I am using mule 3.8 and configuring the output of Data transformer as 'Copybook'. PFB my configurations,

[Data Transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kO8c.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kO8c.png

Here is the copybook file I am using,

```css
        01  COMMAREA.
           05  MQ-CNTL.
               10  MQ-MSGID          PIC X(08).                                                  
        05 INPUT-OUTPUT.                                      
            10  ID1               PIC X(04).
         10  ID2               PIC X(08).
         10  IO-ARRAY  OCCURS 99 INDEXED BY IO-ARRAY.  
           15  ELEMENT1        PIC X(03).
           15  ELEMENT2        PIC X(03).
           15  ELEMENT3        PIC X(01).
           15  ELEMENT4        PIC X(01).
           15  ELEMENT5        PIC X(02).
```

Can you please help resolve this?

Comment: Resolution - https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/63317/what-is-the-dataweave-expression-to-map-an-arrayli.html

Answer (score 0):

As per your Dataweave Configuration, you Just Write only one time in an array of IO-ARRAY but based on your copybook it is expecting 99 times(occurs 99).

I hope you got the point

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that this line:

```
       10  IO-ARRAY  OCCURS 99 INDEXED BY IO-ARRAY.
```

indicates that there is a dependency on the `IO-ARRAY` field. For reference look into the below code snippet.

```
01 WS-TABLE.
  05 WS-A OCCURS 3 TIMES INDEXED BY I.
     10 WS-B PIC A(2).
     10 WS-C OCCURS 2 TIMES INDEXED BY J.
        15 WS-D PIC X(3).
```